# Does being launched by an enemy soldier's rocket crit-boost your market gardener?

Tags: team-fortress-2, tf2-soldier

The market gardener deals critical hits during a rocket jump. Now the question is:

```
 What if the rocket doesn't belong to the jumper?
```

So essentially what would happen is, an enemy soldier shoots at your feet, and you get launched a few feet in the air by his rocket. Now is this considered a rocket jump? In other words, will a successful hit with the market gardener result in a crit at this point?

Comment: Just adding on... This also works with the Direct Hit. If an enemy is launched by you, themselves, or one of your allies, it doesn't matter. The launcher will still mini-crit. Again, just thought I'd add this on :)

Comment: @crayzeedude Thanks for the addition, I was just wondering this today while using the direct hit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, the weapon would still crit.

Market Gardener considers you to be rocket jumping if you are airborne because of any explosion- including explosions from enemy explosive attacks. It still won't count other attacks which could knock you into the air, such as a Pyro's airblast.

The [weapon demonstration](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xr7W3t8qZ60) for the Market Gardener shows a soldier launched into the air by an enemy Demoman's stickies causing a crit.